# How to populate manually from db a form select (multivalued)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In my form i have a simple

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="action[files][]" id="action_files"></select>
```

outputed by  :

```
  $builder->add('files', 'choice', array('multiple' => true, 'required' => false));
```

the `setFiles()` is working, but when displaying an existent record, the `getFiles()` does not work.

Here's the getter :

```
public function getFiles()
{
    $array = array();
    $documents = $this->getDocuments();

    foreach ($documents as $document) {
        $array[$document->getFilename()] = $document->getFilename();
    }
    return $array;
}
```

It'll output :

```
array(1) { ["slide1.jpg"]=> string(10) "slide1.jpg" }
```

**But the select is empty.**

How can i achieve that please ?

Comment: Are you sure that $douments is actually non-empty?

Comment: @MassimilianoArione I'm 120% sure the getDocuments returns the uploaded document. so it's not empty

Comment: Just to be sure: did you try a var_dump($array) in getFiles(), before return?

Comment: Yeah i did it before replying (that's why i replied today and not yesterday :p). it gives me : array(1) { ["adresse_pro.jpg"]=> string(15) "adresse_pro.jpg" }

Comment: You don't have a clue @MassimilianoArione ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass the "choices" option to the choice field.